how to fix the C2666 problem in C++ in operator overloading == in a template class?
Overloading of the == operator and the / operator does not work. I'm still not good at this and I have no idea how to fix it. I think the problem is that the compiler is not sure that "P" has the == operator, but I do not understand why the program cannot be terminated in an emergency when the program encounters such a "P" during operation.
Code:
`#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
template<typename P> class polynomial
{
public:

    P* ptr;
    uint64_t deg;
    polynomial() :polynomial(0) {};
    polynomial(uint64_t size);
    ~polynomial();

    polynomial operator/(const polynomial<P>& other)const;//binary division of a polynomial by a polynomial


    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const polynomial<P>& plnm); // overloading the output operator
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, polynomial<P>& plnm); // overloading the input operator

    polynomial<P>& operator=(const polynomial<P>& other);
    bool operator==(const polynomial<P>& other);
};

template<typename P>bool polynomial<P>::operator==(const polynomial<P>& other)//no working //C2666
{
    if (deg != other.deg)return false;
    else
    {
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < deg; i++)
        {
            if (ptr[i] != other.ptr[i])return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template<typename P>polynomial<P>::polynomial(uint64_t size) {
    deg = size;
    if (size)
        ptr = new P[size];
    else
        ptr = nullptr;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr[i] = 0;

}

template<typename P>polynomial<P>::~polynomial()
{
    delete[] ptr;
}

template<typename P>polynomial<P>& polynomial<P>::operator=(const polynomial<P>& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        delete[] ptr;
        deg = other.deg;
        ptr = new P[deg];

        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < deg; ++i)
        {
            ptr[i] = other.ptr[i];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

template<typename P>std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, polynomial<P>& plnm)
{
    uint64_t new_size;
    in >> new_size;

    polynomial<P> temp(new_size);

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < new_size; ++i)
    {
        in >> temp.ptr[i];
    }

    plnm = temp;

    return in;
}

template<typename P> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const polynomial<P>& plnm)
{
    out << "Degree: " << plnm.deg << ", Coefficients: ";

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < plnm.deg; ++i)
    {
        out << plnm.ptr[i] ;
        if (i==1)
        {   
            out << "x";
        }
        else if (i > 1) {
            out << "x^" << i;
        }
        out <<" ";

    }

    out << std::endl;

    return out;
}

//no working
template<typename P>polynomial<P> polynomial<P>::operator/(const polynomial<P>& other)const
{
    if (deg < other.deg)
    {
        return 0; //i think there working automatic static_cast<P>(0)
    }
    polynomial<P> result(1);
    result.ptr[0] = 1;
    if (deg == other.deg)
    {
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < deg; i++)
        {
            if (ptr[i] != other.ptr[i])result.ptr[0] = 0;return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    using T = int;
    polynomial<T> a;
    std::cin >> a;
    polynomial<T> b;
    std::cin >> b;

    bool c = (a == b);//?            
    std::cout << a<<" " << b << " " <<c;//no working 
    // or
    //std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << (a / b);//no working 
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}`

I tried to add such code first before the general implementation of the == operator, then after. In both cases, I see the error E1449


template<>bool polynomial<int>::operator==(const polynomial<int>& other)//no working //C2666
{
    if (deg != other.deg)return false;
    else
    {
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < deg; i++)
        {
            if (ptr[i] != other.ptr[i])return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

I tried to change the compiler version to c++20, the error did not go away, I also see it in c++17. In addition, in c++17, I see another error, It occurs in the implementation of the "/" operator
The errors that I see
(I'm sorry that part of the text is in my language, if it helps, I can install English and write the errors again):
1:
"
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка (активно)    E1449   явная специализация функцию "polynomial<P>::operator== [с P=int]" должна предшествовать его первому использованию (в строке 150)    песочница   C:\Users\Пользователь\source\repos\песочница\песочница.cpp  24  

"
2:
"
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class polynomial<int> const &)" (??6@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV01@AEBV?$polynomial@H@@@Z) в функции main.   песочница   C:\Users\Пользователь\source\repos\песочница\песочница.obj  1   

"   
3:
"
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class polynomial<int> &)" (??5@YAAEAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV01@AEAV?$polynomial@H@@@Z) в функции main. песочница   C:\Users\Пользователь\source\repos\песочница\песочница.obj  1   
"
4:(as I understand it, it will pass if you fix the second and third)
"
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 2  песочница   C:\Users\Пользователь\source\repos\песочница\x64\Debug\песочница.exe    1   

"


Your "friendly" operator>> and operator<< are not template declarations. You need to write their definitions inside the class definition.

This is tricky. Carefully read this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends

I expect you want braces here: if (ptr[i] != other.ptr[i])result.ptr[0] = 0;return result; unless your intent is an unconditinal return that has nothing to do with the if. I recommend always using braces. The lack of them and putting everything on one line without even whitespace makes your code very hard to read. That tends to lead to bugs.

Don't define polynomial<int>::operator==, since it's no different from the template and its existence complicates the order of things. If the comments so far don't fix your issues, be sure to edit your post to include a minimal reproducible example.

Use of new and delete expressions is an advanced topic in modern C++. Here you could use std::vector<P> instead.
